# Decimal shift customize

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question about how to shift decimal based on demand. 
There is a list of amount which have three distinc values(base, option, amount).
The option has three numbers 0, 1, 2. 
0 means that you should shift the decimal over zero spaces (there is no amount greater than 1 dollar), 1 means that you should shift the decimal right to left by 1 place. and 2 means by 2 places.
Such as the amount is 1234, if the option is 2, then the amount should be 12.34, if the option is 1, the amount should be 1.234.

The code is below:

```
amounts = [(16, 1, '0xad7'),
(8, 2, '0o7125'),
(2, 1, '-0b101001101000'),
(8, 1, '0o2163'),
(16, 2, '0x9ec'),
(2, 2, '-0b10011110111'),
(8, 1, '-0o5074')]
from decimal import Decimal 
for x in range(len(amounts)):

    amount= int(amounts[x][2],base=amounts[x][0])
    amount= Decimal(amount).shift(-amounts[x][1])
    print(amount)
```

I got output like below:

```
277
36
-266
113
25
-12
```

The issues is I only can get the int when I do decimal shift.  for example, if the number is 1234 the option is 4, and I put it into my code, 
I only got 0 rather than 0.1234.

Comment: "I got error": what error? I can see at least three errors in your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry about that, Just edited.

Comment: You still have a syntax error so I doubt that is your real code. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compute this manually instead of using a library, just divide the number by 10 however many times specified for each number. This shifts the decimal right a certain amount of times, assuming 2345 maps to 0.2345 as the starting number.

Example:

```
amounts=[(1, 2345), (0, 3345), (2, 1223)]

for x in range(len(amounts)):
    divide_count, amount = amounts[x]
    loop_times = len(str(amount)) - divide_count

    # Keep dividing the number by 10
    for x in range(loop_times):
        amount = amount / 10.0

    print(amount)
```

Output of running this is:

```
2.345
0.3345
12.23
```

---

Edit: I also just realized, since it is always being divided by 10 the while loop is not necessary. You can simply divide `amount` by 10<sup>len(amount) - n</sup> where `n` is the `divide_count` and `len(amount)` is the number of digits that `amount` has.

Example using power of 10:

```
amounts=[(1, 2345), (0, 3345), (2, 1223)]

for x in range(len(amounts)):
    divide_count, amount = amounts[x]
    power_amount = len(str(amount)) - divide_count

    amount = amount / (10.0 ** power_amount)
    print(amount)
```

Comment: Thank you Karl, I never thought about using while loop

Comment: Hi Karl, thank you so much for the help, but there is a small question if the divide _count is zero, what will be the way to get the correct number?  for example,  the amount is 1234 and the divide_count is 0, I want to get 0.1234.

Comment: Why would 1234 become 0.1234 if you're shifting the number by 0? I thought 0  means you wouldn't be shifting the number at all?

Comment: Hi Karl, the  0 means that you should shift the decimal over zero spaces (there is no amount greater than 1 dollar) I just get it when I add else:
        option= 10.0** len(str(amount))
        amount = amount/option .         Also, what will be the best way to sum all amount?

Comment: I am confused then, it seems like you're saying you compute something completely different when the shift amount is 0. I thought you were shifting the decimal left, but now you are saying to shift the decimal right. What exactly do the original numbers represent? Is 2345 -> 2345 or 2345 -> 0.2345 originally before shifting?

Comment: Hi Karl, sorry about the confusion, the requirement is shifting the decimal right.

Comment: I updated my answer, it can still be done by dividing the amount by a power of 10, just done using the difference between the length of the amount given.

Comment: Thank you very much Karl. Reall appreciated it.